# Getting error while launching iOS app on Appium Inspector

Tags: appium, appium-ios, python-appium, appium-desktop

**I have configured everything on my macbook to launch iOS app through appium inspector.
I have successfully installed web driver agent application on my device as shown in screenshot below**

[image]

**Below are my Desired capabilites for iOS device:**
[image]

**While launching App I'm getting error as shown in below screenshot. Please guide me what is the issue here?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65" indicates that there's a problem with building the WebDriverAgent project, which is used by Appium to automate iOS apps. This error is often related to issues with Xcode or the configuration of the WebDriverAgent project.

You can follow [this](https://medium.com/@linga-sydney/how-to-setup-appium-android-ios-d6780b93be21) link for setting up WDA.